# изменение объекта при присвоении

Tags: c++, классы, объекты

Можно ли при случае:

```
A* a = new A();
A* b = a;
```

сделать так чтобы вызывался оператор присвоения класса A в котором происходили бы изменения общих данных? Понимаю, что можно сделать к примеру что-то такое:

```
A* a = new A();
A* b = a;
*b = *a;
```

но можно ли обойтись только этим кодом:

```
A* b = a;
```

?

Comment: Не можно - тут речь идет об указателях. В случае с указателями методы класса не задействуются.

Comment: Вам нужна какая-то обвязка из умных указателей, написанных собственноручно.

Comment: Нельзя. А вообще это похоже на проблему XY.

Comment: возможно, это попытка написать свой санитейзер или отладить проблему